# Serving files through controllers with partial download support

Tags: grails, download, controller, partial

I need to serve files through grails, only users with permission have access, so I cant serve them with a static link to a container. The system is able to stream binary files to the client without problems,but now (for bandwidth performance issues on the client) I need to implement segmented or partial downloads in the controllers.

Theres a plugin or proven solution to this problem?
May be some kind of tomcat/apache plugin to restrict access to files with certain rules or temporal tickets so I can delegate the "resume download" or "segmented download" problem to the container.

Also i need to log and save stats on the downloads of the users.
I need good performance so, I think doing this in the controller is not good idea.

Sorry bad english.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin **for apache** - https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/ It doesn't matter what you're using behind apache at this case. By using this plugin you will respond with special header `X-SENDFILE`, with path to file to serve, and Apache will take care about actual file downloading for current request.

If you're using Nginx, you have to use `X-Accel-Redirect` header, see http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile